# How can I do an rsync that asks for a confirmation for each individual file?

Tags: rsync

I have a small number of files to sync from one server to another, however there are some files I want to exclude from being synced.

I'd rather not have to add them to a --exclude pattern if I can just confirm for each file instead. Is it possible to get a prompt for each file saying something like "Sync this file? (y/N)"

Answer (score 2):

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) is designed to be a bidirectional rsync. You can nonetheless use it in one direction if you wish. Unison prompts you to decide what to do for each file; press `>` to copy forward or `/` to skip a file. There's also a GUI if you prefer that.

Alternatively, you can link the files into a staging area, then synchronize the stating area and clean it up.

```
mkdir staging
for x in files_to_mostly_copy/*; do
  printf "Copy %s? " "$x"
  read response
  case "$response" in
    [Yy]*) ln "$x" staging/;;
  esac
done
rsync -au staging/ remote_server:
rm -r staging
```